# How to get strings 'aa', ab' up to 'yz', 'zz'?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How to get strings from 'aa' up to 'zz' in a list?
I know it is obvious, but don't know the proper idiom to solve that kind of problems. Just show the idea with concrete examples and I'll figure out the rest.
Thanks.

Tried

```
(++) <$> ['a'..'z'] <*> ['a'..'z']
```

but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Why not use a list comprehension? `[[x, y] | x <- ['a'..'z'], y <- ['a'..'z']]`

Comment: You don't want `(++)` here because it takes as inputs lists and not characters. E.g. `liftA (\x y -> [x,y])` has the desired behaviour. For future reference, if you have code which doesn't compile, include the error you actually get.

Comment: You can make `(++)` work here with `[[x] ++ [y] | x <- ['a'..'z'], y <- ['a'..'z']]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these do what you want (remember `String = [Char]`):

```
Control.Monad.replicateM 2 ['a'..'z'] -- Cleanest; generalizes to all Applicatives
sequence $ replicate 2 ['a'..'z'] -- replicateM n = sequenceA . replicate n
-- sequence = sequenceA for monads
-- sequence means cartesian product for the [] monad

[[x, y] | x <- ['a'..'z'], y <- ['a'..'z']] -- Easiest for beginners
do x <- ['a'..'z']
   y <- ['a'..'z']
   return [x, y] -- For when you forget list comprehensions exist/need another monad
['a'..'z'] >>= \x -> ['a'..'z'] >>= \y -> return [x, y] -- Desugaring of do
-- Also, return x = [x] in this case
concatMap (\x -> map (\y -> [x, y]) ['a'..'z']) ['a'..'z'] -- Desugaring of comprehension
-- List comprehensions have similar syntax to do-notation and mean about the same,
-- but they desugar differently

(\x y -> [x, y]) <$> ['a'..'z'] <*> ['a'..'z'] -- When you're being too clever
(. return) . (:) <$> ['a'..'z'] <*> ['a'..'z'] -- Same as ^ but pointfree
```

The reason

```
(++) <$> ['a'..'z'] <*> ['a'..'z']
```

doesn't work is because you need `(++) :: Char -> Char -> [Char]`, but you only have `(++) :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]`. You can throw in `returns`s on top of the arguments to `(++)` to put the `Char`s into singleton lists and get things to work:

```
(. return) . (++) . return <$> ['a'..'z'] <*> ['a'..'z']
```